# How can I use "find" in a shell script to search from the current directory?

Tags: directory, scripts, find

I want the program to look like this :

```
read a
if[ find . name $a ]; then
  echo "You found the file"
else "You haven t found the file"
fi
```

Comment: Could you please clarify..are you meant to find files in the current directory only or you want to traverse the subdirectory hierarchy stating from current directory too?

Comment: I meant to find only the files in the current directory

Comment: Your comment seems self-contradictory. If you do not want to consider subdirectories recursively, then the question title is misleading, and `find` is a poor tool to use.

Comment: Well, in that case use `-maxdepth 1` while using `find` so that `find` won't traverse to any subdirectory, also note that `find` would be a overkill in that case..you could just use `test -e` with `if`..

Comment: @CiobanuRares Does the variable `a` contain the literal name of a single file whose presence you're trying to test for? Or could `$a` expand to a glob pattern like `foo*`? Or does the shell variable expansion `$a` not actually appear in your script all, and is only a [metasyntactic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) representing a filename or glob pattern that appears literally in the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not anything was found, `find` always returns true. You can use `grep` to determine if `find` found something:

```sh
read -r a
if find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$a" -print -quit | grep -q . 
then
  echo "You found the file"
else 
  echo "You haven't found the file"
fi
```

Quitting after the first match (`-print -quit`) should improve performance, as Eliah has noted. Use `-maxdepth 1` to limit results to the current directory - but then `find` is overkill for this.

Comment: Since Ubuntu has GNU find, `-print -quit` can be added to the end of the `find` command to [*slightly* improve performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13860/11938). You could even print only a blank line: `-printf '\n' -quit` This doesn't change `find`'s exit status, of course; piping to `grep -q` remains necessary.

Comment: @EliahKagan does it make much of a difference? `grep` will quit after the first line is read, the pipe will be closed and `find` will have to quit anyway.

Comment: [According to Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13880/11938), it can improve performance due to buffered I/O. That is, before the output is read, `find` will continue walking the directory hierarchy. I suppose that, if there are many more directories to search but no other matches, the performance improvement could be significant.

Comment: muru, could you please modify the answer a bit, i know OP has chosen it as accepted but they actually want to [look for only in the current directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622803/how-can-i-use-find-in-a-shell-script-to-search-from-the-current-directory?noredirect=1#comment882069_622803)

Comment: @muru You might mention `-mindepth 1` too. If `"$a"` expands to a literal filename, it won't be needed here: that name is unlikely to be `.`. But to search a single directory with `find` whose name is not given as `.`, or (sometimes) when `"$a"` expands to a glob rather than a literal filename, `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth1` may need to be used in a script. Btw, I wonder if perhaps `find` is not overkill for searching the current directory after all: if the value of `a` is a glob, `find -name "$a"` expands it; I don't know of any elegant way to  achieve such double-indirection with the shell alone.

Answer (score 2):

If don't *have* to use the `find` command, using the `test` command (or its short form `[`...`]`) would be easier, IMHO. With `test`, the `e` switch does what you're looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r a
if [[ -e $a ]]; then
    echo "You found the file"
else
    echo "You haven't found the file"
fi
```

But be aware that `test` only looks for the file in the current directory, not in any subdirectories (thanks to EliahKagan for the reminder).

You can find a good overview about `test` at the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

Comment: @EliahKagan , as does the `find` command in the question. So I'd assume that's what he's asking for.

Comment: @EliahKagan OP has used `search the current directory` in the heading although used `find` in the example..its a bit confusing ..i think as far as the heading is concerned this is a valid answer..

Comment: `find` is recursive. Without `-maxdepth`, it will search as far down as it can.

Comment: @EliahKagan Ah, yes, you're right of course. I forgot about that.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck you can probably enable `extglob` and test for existence of `**/$a`.

Comment: @muru But `**/$a` wouldn't find `$a` if it's in the current dir directly, if I remember correctly. So I'd have to combine two tests, and then it wouldn't be easier than using `find` anymore.

Comment: Since you initially suggest `test` and `[`...`]`, which aren't equivalent to [the `[[` shell keyword](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) in the example, you may want to clarify how syntax should be modified for `test` or `[`. Unlike `[[` (where it works either way), `$a` should be quoted when passed as an argument to `test`/`[`, unless known not to contain whitespace. Also, whether or not `[[` is used, if the filename read by `read -r a` contains leading or trailing whitespace, it will be trimmed off--so unless that is desired, use `IFS read -r a` to prevent it.